# What are practical uses of mountable engines?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Just finished watching "Railscast 277" on mountable engines in Rails, what are practical uses of mountable engines?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best examples would be Devise (for authentication) which is an engine (plugin) but its mounted as a shared-engine; you also get namespaced engines and this helps to retain a sense of context.

Another example would be the Active Admin add-on, error notification plugins...and a whole lot more.  In terms of 'mounting' from a purely routing point of view, you can see how — with a namespaced engine you can serve a completely isolated rails app from a route from within your app itself.

You should consider [reading this](http://www.builtfromsource.com/2010/12/13/mountable-engines-in-rails-3-1-beta-getting-started/) as well.

Answer (score 1):

Two major uses:

- Reusability. Gems that expose a lot of application functionality are often distributed as engines.
- Modularity. Particularly for large applications, there are often parts of the application that don't seem like they want to be mixed in with the main application, yet are too closely related to be extracted to entirely separate applications. Engines can work well for this.

[Spree](http://www.spreecommerce.com) takes this to extremes: the core Spree framework is the main Rails application, and to customize it, you write engines. This means you're never modifying the Spree core directly.